# html link with php header() redirection

Tags: php, html, redirect, header

when I am redirecting with "a href .." to another page I lose all my SESSION variables.
So I want to redirect only by using header() php function.
How I can create a link that when the user use it redirects him to another page using header()?
Thank you

here is my code:
source page:

```
session_save_path("myrootdir/cgi-bin/tmp");
session_start();
....
$id = $_SESSION['id']; //session variable passed succesfully from log in page
$usr = $_SESSION['usr'];//by using header('sourcepage.php');
....
< a href='http://targetpage.php'>target< / a>
```

target page:

```
session_save_path("myrootdir/cgi-bin/tmp");
session_start();
...
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['usr'])) {
   echo "success";
}
else{
   echo "failed to pass";
}
```

I always get failed to pass!

**UPDATE**

now I have another strange issue...

```
$_SESSION['id']=$_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['usr']=$_POST['usr'];

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['usr'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $usr = $_SESSION['usr'];
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '". mysql_real_escape_string( $id ) ."' AND usr = '". mysql_real_escape_string( $usr ) ."'");
    echo "Welcome ".$usr;
    echo "Session id".session_id();
    if(mysql_num_rows($qry) != 1) { Destroy(); }
  } else { Destroy(); }
```

when I check if someone is logged in like this it works perfect in every page but when I remove the echo lines then it calls Destroy() function.

Comment: using header redirection I dont have any problem. By using html href redirection I lose all my SESSION vars. You mean I have to call exit() inside href ?

Comment: I use session_start on every page

Comment: ok i edited the question with the code

Comment: Where is `header()` function call?

Comment: the header('sourcepage.php') is in the log in page which redirects to the sourcepage.php with the session variables succesfully

Comment: I updated my answer, and added example. But according to code you give, session wars shoul be ok. check if your session starts ok.

Comment: I printed the session_id in both pages and its the same so I think that session starts ok in both pages (source and target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works only if you call "header" before any output to browser, including tags. 
So I supose it not the best idea to use "header".

If you losing SESSION variables, try to add some JavaScript that will create form whith vars you need inside inputs, and submit it to new page.

Is this redirection inside one domain?

**UPDATE:**

php code on current page:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="sessionID" style="display: none;" value="'.$_SESSION['id'].'">';
echo '<input type="text" id="sessionUri" style="display: none;" value="'.$_SESSION['usr'].'">';
```

JS code:

```
< a onclick="sendSessionVars()">target< / a>

<script>
    function sendSessionVars(){
        var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var sessionId=document.getElementById('sessionID').value;
        var sessionUri=document.getElementById('sessionUri').value;
        var form=document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method','post');
        form.setAttribute('style','display:none');
        form.setAttribute('action','targetpage.php');
        body.appendChild(form);
        var id=document.createElement('input');
        id.setAttribute('type','hidden');
        id.setAttribute('name','id');
        id.setAttribute('value',sessionId);
        var usr=document.createElement('input');
        usr.setAttribute('type','hidden');
        usr.setAttribute('name','usr');
        usr.setAttribute('value',sessionUri);
        form.appendChild(id);
        form.appendChild(usr);
        form.submit();  
    }
</script>
```

on jQuery would be much less code, but it will work slower.

and php code on target page:

```
$_SESSION['id']=$_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['usr']=$_POST['usr'];
```

You can also post it to some vars.
It's pretty straightforward way.

But you should not lose SESSION variables. Check is your session_start(); is ok.

Comment: yes its inside the same domain. I use < a href='http://www.mysite.com/page1.php > page1 < /a > . Can you give me an example in javascript to pass the $_SESSION['usr'] and $_SESSION['id'] vars to the new page?

Comment: it worked! thank you! but I have a strange issue now! please check update in main question

Answer (score 1):

header("Location: yourpage.php")
try this

Comment: I want to have a link on my page so when the user clicks it the redirects him using header()

Answer (score 0):

In php use it header('Location:page_name.php')
But I prefer to use javascript cause you might headers problem using it alot
So here is my javascript

```
       echo "<script>window.location='page.php'</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `header("Location:some.php")`

and putting header redirect before html tag is a good practice. You might want to reconstruct your website structure, if you find that it is below the html tag.